# "[].forEach"?​​

Tags: javascript

I saw this script somewhere else, and it will check every single checkboxes:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(el){
       el.checked=true;
    }
);​
```

I know how to use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
[0,1,2].forEach(function(num){
    console.log(num);
});

//0
//1
//2
```

But now, it is `[].forEach`, and there is nothing inside. So why does it still work? Why can't I do this instead?

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(el){
       el.checked=true;
    }
);​
```

Comment: You can. The first ends up being the same through reflection. Check `call`and `apply`.

Comment: Note that this `[].forEach.call( nodeList, fn )` technique **doesn't work in IE8**, so you cannot use it in general circumstances.

Comment: You can *technically* add the method to use it on a result of `querySelectorAll`, but it's a road fraught with peril. `NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;`

Comment: @amnotiam: It's too bad IE8 doesn't have a `NodeList` type. Life would be much easier.

Comment: @minitech: So many things would be easier, but for IE. Anyway, I didn't realize it doesn't have NodeList. Interesting. I read that famous Kangax article on extending the DOM, and never bothered with messing with it after that.

Comment: @amnotiam, minitech, Šime Vidas: Nothing to do with `NodeList`, it doesn't work because there is no `Array.prototype.forEach` in IE8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript has first-class functions; that is, they're treated like objects, and can have their own properties and methods. The built in [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method takes a `this` parameter for the function as its first argument, and the rest of the arguments are passed to the function itself. The array `[]` is not used, except as a means to access the (less concise, so less used) `Array.prototype.forEach` method.

It's basically a rebinding of [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for use on something that is not an array, in this case a `NodeList`. If `NodeList`s offered a `forEach` method, then it would be equivalent to, and you may read it as, this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(el) {
   el.checked = true;
});​
```

---

So, a little more in depth. `call` will execute a function with a different context. `forEach` iterates over the context and calls the function it is passed as its argument. So a `someFunc.call(thisArg, otherArg)` will be executed as if it were in the context of `thisArg`, like `thisArg.someFunc(otherArg)`. Here's the simplest example:

```
function callMe(something) {
    return something + this;
}

callMe('Hello'); // Hellonull or Hello[object Window] or something
callMe.call({}, 'World'); // World[object Object]
```

[`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) works the same way, but you pass an array of arguments as the second argument.

Comment: Wait what? So it is a `NodeList` instead of a `Array`? Isn't a `NodeList` *is* an `Array`?

Comment: Nope, a `NodeList` is *not* an `Array`. However, fundamentally, it behaves just like an `Array`--it has numeric indices and a `length` property. It just doesn't inherit the standard `Array` methods. However, if a `method` only needs indexing and `length`, it would work, which is why this particular snippet of code is valid.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis - So it is an `Array` without the methods that an `Array` should have. I see.

Comment: @Derek: Formally, it's not an `Array` either; just try `document.getElementsByTagName('p') instanceof Array`. But it pretends it's one, which is *really, really annoying* sometimes :)

Comment: A cute way to think about it would be that it is not a "capital A" `Array`, but it is an *array* in the practical sense. Just like the `arguments` object. It's just JavaScript's way of adding some excitement to your otherwise dull life :).

Comment: `It's just JavaScript's way of adding some excitement to your otherwise dull life` Ha ha :D

Answer (score 4):

This is just using `[]` to get the `forEach` function. Once it has the function, it uses `.call` to call it as if it was a method of `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')`.

This is useful because the result of `document.querySelectorAll` is not an `Array` but behaves just like one, so we can reuse the standard `Array` methods.

When you use `.call`, the first argument is used as the `this` value. That is, in this particular snippet, every time `this` is encountered inside the source of `forEach`, it is set to `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')`.

You can't just call `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(...` directly because `querySelectorAll` does *not* return an `Array` object and so does not have a `forEach` method. The whole `.call` thing is just a way to get around this by calling `forEach` *as if* it was a method of `NodeList`, which is what is actually returned.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).  It applies (sets `this` to) the results of `document.querySelectorAll` to `forEach`, so that it iterates over those results rather than the (empty) array on the left-hand side of the dot.